# Spring rest api filter fields in the response

Tags: json, spring, rest, filter

I am using spring rest api 4.x. We have a requirement to filter the fields in the response based on the request parameters.

My User object:

```
private class UserResource {
   private String userLastName;
   private String userFirstName;
   private String email;
   private String streetAddress;
}

E.g. URL:  curl -i http://hostname:port/api/v1/users?fields=firstName,lastName.
```

In this case I need to return only the fields which are in the request param "fields". JSON output should contain only firstName, lastName.

There are several ways filter the fields in Jackson based on the object. In my case I need to filter dynamically by passing the list of fields to Jackson serializer.

Please share some ideas.

Answer (score 18):

Thanks Ali. It is a great help. Let me implement it today. I will post the result

```
@JsonFilter("blah.my.UserEntity")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
//fields goes here
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public MappingJacksonValue getUsers(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params) {
//Build pageable here
Page<UserEntity> users = userService.findAll(pageable);

    MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(users);
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("blah.my.UserEntity", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
                        .filterOutAllExcept("userFirstName"));
    mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filters);
    return mappingJacksonValue;
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful for me

Answer (score 3):

Use a `ResponseBodyAdvice` in order to change the response before it got written to the HTTP response. In `beforeBodyWrite(...)` method you have access to the current `ServerHttpRequest` which you can read the `fields` value. Your body advice would look like following:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyResponseBodyAdvisor implements ResponseBodyAdvice<UserResource> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return returnType.getParameterType().equals(UserResource.class);
    }

    @Override
    public UserResource beforeBodyWrite(UserResource body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        String fields = ((ServletServerHttpRequest) request).getServletRequest().getParameter("fields");
        // body.set...(null) for each field not in fields

        return body;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ali, In your solution, we are making fields empty. But I dont want to display the field at all. I implemented as described in SPR-12586. Thanks.

Comment: Annotate your dto with `@JsonInclude` to remove the `empty` fields from the response

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is supported in Spring 4.2 as per https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12586 via Jackson `JsonFilter` (though the jira is returning an error at the moment).

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for the response. It was very helpful.

Comment: Here is my solution. MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(MyObject);  In your controller just return mappingJacksonValue. make sure MyObject has @JsonFilter("myObject") annotation.