# Jackson Field filter in Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a spring boot application and I need to filter response body from RequestParam

Example :

```
  // DTO
   public class PersonDTO
   {
      private Long id;
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
   }

   // Controller
   public class PersonController
   {
      @GetMapping(value = "/person")
      public ResponseEntity<List<PersonDTO>> getPerson(@RequestParam(required = false) String filters)
      {
         List<PersonDTO> personList = myservoce.getPerson();
         return new ResponseEntity<List<PersonDTO>>(personList, HttpStatus.OK);
      }
   }
```

***Example of client query:***

return all person without fields filter

http://localhost:8080/person

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "firstName": "toto1",
    "lastName": "titi2"
  },
  {
    "id": 345,
    "firstName": "toto2",
    "lastName": "titi2"
  }
]
```

return all person and the response contain just firstName and lastName:
http://localhost:8080/person?filters=firstName,lastName

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "toto1",
    "lastName": "titi2"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "toto2",
    "lastName": "titi2"
  }
]
```

I have found this API "[jackson-dynamic-filter](https://github.com/shihyuho/jackson-dynamic-filter)", but the filter is used as annotation like this :

```
public class PersonController
{
   @FilterOutAllExcept({"firstName", "lastName"})
   @GetMapping(value = "/person")
   public ResponseEntity<List<PersonDTO>> getPerson( @RequestParam(required = false) String filters )
   {
      List<PersonDTO> personList = myservoce.getPerson();
      return new ResponseEntity<List<PersonDTO>>(personList, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

in my case I cannot use this API because the list of field filter are managed by the client and it can be different for each call and my real payload Dto contain a lot of field

I have found also this API "[jackson-antpathfilter](https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter)" but it not work for me and also the response type is MappingJacksonValue and not a  ResponseEntity>

Any idea how I can configure this use case with spring application ?

Comment: Same problem here. I can't believe there is not a clean and easy way to do that. Did you find another way to solve this problem than the answer you wrote ? I tried to change the spring configuration to retrieve the ObjectMapper and configure it before calling return with ResponseEntity, but then I have other kinds of strange problems that I don't know how to solve which make me feel like it is not the right way to solve the problem.

Comment: I have add a temporary solution below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring rest api filter fields in the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158064/spring-rest-api-filter-fields-in-the-response)

Answer (score 1):

I have found temporary this solution :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonFilterAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<List<?>>
{

   @Override
   public List<?> beforeBodyWrite(
      List<?> arg0,
      MethodParameter arg1,
      MediaType arg2,
      Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> arg3,
      ServerHttpRequest arg4,
      ServerHttpResponse arg5)
   {
      HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ((ServletServerHttpRequest) arg4).getServletRequest();
      String[] params = servletRequest.getParameterValues("filters");
      if (params != null)
      {
        // parse object and set field to null
      }
      return arg0;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean supports(MethodParameter arg0, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> arg1)
   {
      // return true if method parameters contain 'filters' field
      return true;
   }
```

any other suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This is from my web service, you can use this code and adapt to your model and repository. From this you can create a generic service and call your modified version wherever you need it.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/entidades/{id}/campos", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Retrieves requested object fields", response = Entidade.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getFields(@Valid @PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam String campos) {
        final Optional<Entidade> ent = entidadeRepository.findById(id);
        final String[] camposArr = campos.split(",");

        if (ent.isPresent()) {
            final Entidade e = ent.get();
            Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
            for (String campo : camposArr) {
                String methodName = "get" + (campo.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + campo.substring(1));
//                System.out.println(campo);
                try {
                    Method method = e.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
//                    System.out.println(method.invoke(e));
                    result.put(campo, method.invoke(e));
                } catch (Exception err) {
                }

            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);

        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add annotation `@JsonIgnore` of Jackson lib to filter field `id`:

```
public class PersonDTO implements Serializable
{
  @JsonIgnore
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}
```

Comment: PersonDto is just an example  ! and in this example the filter can be a combination of some fields
( id & firstName ) ( lastName & firstName ) ( id ) ( firstName ) ....
so if we add annotation @JsonIgnore for a specific field the filter cannot be dynamic, please look at my answer